# Gridlines in excel sheet are disappearing by default after table export from vf page into excel sheet

Tags: visualforce, data-export

I have successfully exported the table in visualforce page into an excel sheet, but after opening the sheet grid lines are disappearing by default.

How to show gridlines automatically when the file is opened?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you can't.

Turning a Visualforce page into an "Excel" file (by including `contenttype="application/vnd.ms-excel"` in the `<apex:page>` tag) is just Salesforce taking advantage of some compatibility features in Excel. Using Salesforce isn't turning your Visualforce page into a "real" .xls or .xlsx file, so any styling that you apply to your Visualforce page *will not be reflected in Excel*.

[Caspar Harmer goes into more detail about what you would need to do](https://www.soliantconsulting.com/blog/stylish-spreadsheets-visualforce/) to get some *basic* styling, but be warned that it means your "Visualforce" page's sole purpose will be to create an XML file that Excel can use.

Comment: Thank you, problem solved not completely but using CSS we have got gridlines in the excel sheet.